# View doesn't appear after changing the view property 'isHidden = false'

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uikit

I'm developing an iOS application and then the issue that I have faced now is showing a view using the view property `isHidden`.

I initialized a custom view including a CAAnimation and then set the default `isHidden` property `true` to hide. After a certain condition meets I changed the `isHidden` property to `false` to show it. But in this case the view doesn't appear.

```
    private func setupButtonEffectView() {
      self.buttonEffectView = ButtonEffectView()
      self.buttonEffectView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
//      self.view.addSubview(self.buttonEffectView!)
      self.view.insertSubview(self.buttonEffectView!, belowSubview: self.button!)

      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        self.buttonEffectView!.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.button!.centerXAnchor),
        self.buttonEffectView!.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.button!.centerYAnchor),
        self.buttonEffectView!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
        self.buttonEffectView!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
        ])

      self.buttonEffectView!.isHidden = true
    }
```

I created the button effect using the method above.

Comment: You may need to add how and where to set hidden false. So people help you without guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of hiding the view, setting the alpha to 0.0. `self.buttonEffectView.alpha = 0.0`. Then when you want to show it set the alpha to 1.0.